# How can an SD Card go thermonuclear

Tags: sd-card, micro-sd-card, memory-card

About 5 days ago i got a 128GB micro SD card from a store and it worked great and was really fast possably because it was brand new, but recently today i noticed that the computer i put it in did not recognize it nor did it acknowledge it as being present as a couple of minutes later i smelled something getting hot and thought it was the CPU in my computer but then i noticed when setting it down i touched the SD card slot and noticed it was really hot and pulled it out as i also noticed that it melted the adapter it was in, so in conclusion how can an SD card go thermonuclear in this manner

10/10/16 1121 Edit

here is a link to the photos i had taken

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6T3BZjhU-JFZjFpTlNSWnR1QUk

Comment: So are you going to ask for a refund on the card and adapter?  Obviously, it was a defective card.

Comment: A short inside the sd card, or a short in the sd slot.

Comment: @lixter1234 Yes I plan to but i plan to try  to get another at some other point in time

Comment: @Paul I kinda figured that but what i dont get is how when it was doing well for about 5 days, granted i did forget to unplug it but that should of not made much of a difference as the computer would just ignore it and disable power to the SD card slot after some time and i have left cards in there for upwards of about 2 to 3 months before removing them as i am actively using them and no not for some sort of server and or NAS like storage in case if you were wondering

Comment: Well lets assume a short inside the adapter.  The tracks are fairly fine where the sd connects to the adapter.  Lets say something conductive got in there, but not enough to cause a problem. But then the card got a bit hotter, and things got tighter, and the conductive thing managed to bridge some tracks.